# How to cd to path in a variable in bash script

Tags: bash

Im trying to do cd to a path that is in variable called path. But cannot cd into it.

```
$repo="test"
path="~/code/forks/$repo/client"
echo $path #echoing correct working path
cd "$path"
pwd
```

Comment: `~` isn't expanded when the variable is quoted.

Comment: Changing to `$HOME` is another easy fix.

Comment: Also, it should be `repo=`, not `$repo=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotes are preventing the shell from expanding `~` to your home directory. (`~` is a shell feature, not an actual directory name.)

```
path=~/code/forks/$repo/client
```

This expands `~` during the assignment, not when the parameter is expanded.